# Query performance bottleneck

Tags: mysql, performance, mysql-5.5, optimization, query-performance

I have below query

```
SELECT 
    advertiser_id,
    campaigns_has_clickserver_campaigns.campaigns_campaign_id campaign_id,
    pubid,
    YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(clk.click_time)) y,
    MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(clk.click_time)) m,
    DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(clk.click_time)) d,
    COUNT(clk.click_id) clicks
FROM
    offers
        INNER JOIN
    otherDB.mt_campaigns c ON c.camp_id = cs_camp
        INNER JOIN
    otherDB.mt_offers o ON o.camp_id = cs_camp
        AND o.offer_number = cs_offer
        INNER JOIN
    thisDB.campaigns_has_clickserver_campaigns ON clicksrever_campaign_id = concat_cs_camp_cs_offer
        INNER JOIN
    otherDB.mt_click clk ON clk.camp_id = cs_camp
        AND clk.offer_id = o.offer_id
        AND (clk.click_c1 = offers.original_pubid
        OR clk.click_c2 = offers.original_pubid
        OR clk.click_c3 = offers.original_pubid
        OR clk.click_c4 = offers.original_pubid
        OR clk.click_c5 = offers.original_pubid
        OR clk.click_c6 = offers.original_pubid
        OR clk.click_c7 = offers.original_pubid
        OR clk.click_c8 = offers.original_pubid
        OR clk.click_c9 = offers.original_pubid
        OR clk.click_c10 = offers.original_pubid)
GROUP BY pubid , advertiser_id , campaigns_has_clickserver_campaigns.campaigns_campaign_id , YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(clk.click_time)) , MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(clk.click_time)) , DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(clk.click_time))
LIMIT 0 , 10000;
```

Explain Result

```
+----+-------------+-------------------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table                               | type   | possible_keys                                                                                                                                                        | key                         | key_len | ref                                                                    | rows   | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+-------------------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | offers                              | ALL    | idx_camp_offer_pubid6                                                                                                                                                | NULL                        | NULL    | NULL                                                                   | 103502 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | o                                   | ref    | PRIMARY,idxClick,idxClick1,idxStats                                                                                                                                  | idxClick1                   | 4       | reachef_advertisers.offers.cs_camp,reachef_advertisers.offers.cs_offer |      1 | Using where; Using index        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | campaigns_has_clickserver_campaigns | ref    | idx_clicksrever_campaign_id                                                                                                                                          | idx_clicksrever_campaign_id | 98      | func                                                                   |     30 | Using where                     |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | c                                   | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                                                                                              | PRIMARY                     | 3       | reachef_advertisers.offers.cs_camp                                     |      1 | Using where; Using index        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | clk                                 | ref    | PRIMARY,idxC1,idxOff,idxLpOff,idxBrand,idxNameModel,idxFullName,idxMarketing,idxDeviceType,idxDeviceSize,idxResolution,idxSpeed,idxCarrier,idxIsp,idxCountry,idxCamp | idxC1                       | 3       | reachef_advertisers.offers.cs_camp                                     |    542 | Using where                     |
+----+-------------+-------------------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+---------------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I have tried a lot of indexes on `offers` table but nothing is being used , its killing the complete server , query is even not able to complete in 10 mins

Below is the table structure for `offers` even I tried with MEMORY engine as well.

```
mysql> show create table offers\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: offers
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `offers` (
  `pubid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `advertiser_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cs_camp` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cs_offer` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `original_pubid` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `concat_cs_camp_cs_offer` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `idx_camp_offer_pubid6` (`cs_camp`,`cs_offer`,`concat_cs_camp_cs_offer`,`original_pubid`,`pubid`,`advertiser_id`)
) ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Can you use your app to store clk.click_time's year, month and day as separate fields? 5.7 and MariaDB have `COMPUTED` fields which can do this automatically.

Comment: It's probably the last join which kills performance. `OR` is alway bad in a join and then it's using columns from 3 tables, `o`, `offers` and `clk`. Check if you can change `clk.offer_id = o.offer_id` to `clk.offer_id = offers.offer_id`

Comment: Looks like a table design issue. The click columns should use an EAV design where they become rows in a table and not columns.

Comment: What tables are these columns in? `GROUP BY pubid , advertiser_id , campaigns_has_clickserver_campaigns.campaigns_campaign_id , `

Comment: Are you really ready to handle a resultset of 10K rows?

Comment: Since you have no filtering, the query needs to run through all `offers`, etc.  So it will take a lot of time.  Can you cut back on the number of tables involved?